# How to zoom in to fit the exact bounding box in Autodesk forge viewer

Tags: zooming, screenshot, bounding-box, autodesk-viewer

We want to zoom-in to a 2D sheet in forge-viewer to take screenshot and stitch multiple screenshot later to get better image quality. 
We are facing issue to zoom-in to exact bounding box, it always is little less zoomed-in i.e. we can see portion of sheet which shouldn't be part of screenshot.
Take a case of dividing a 2D sheet in equal 4 quadrants to zoom-in and take screenshot (we can increase quadrants/sections as per the required image quality later), we use below code to zoom-in,

```
var max = viewer.model.getBoundingBox().max;
var min = viewer.model.getBoundingBox().min;
var Q1Min = new THREE.Vector3( min.x, min.y, 0 )
var Q1Max = new THREE.Vector3( (min.x)+(max.x)/2, (min.y)+(max.y)/2, 0 )
var Q1Box =  new THREE.Box3(Q1Min, Q1Max);
viewer.navigation.fitBounds( immediate, Q1Box);

We also tried using below method, it also produces same result
viewer.impl.setViewFromViewBox(viewer.model, [Q1Min.x,Q1Min.y,Q1Max.x,Q1Max.y],'Q1',true)
```

[Full sheet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwZQC.png) as seen in browser.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxmSa.png) after above code execution.

[Required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxflj.png), notice the difference in width of image. In some case height and width both become an issue.

Comment: Can confirm to be able to replicate the issue ... checking with Engineering to find a workaround and will get back soon

Comment: While we wait for Engineering to get back you might want to manually zoom towards the pivot - try `viewer.navigation.setView(camera.position,viewer.navigation.getTarget())`

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thanks for the reply. We tried above method to setView but that also didn't work. We used the camera we got from viewer, is that the right way? Have we received any reply from engineering team.

Comment: Is it possible to zoom-in to exact bounding box? or Should we be looking for other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Engineering came back and offered the same workaround - and see a live sample I just put together to zoom in programmatically [here](https://jsbin.com/lobidej/edit?html,js):

```
  var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
  camera.getWorldDirection( direction );
  camera.position.add( direction.multiplyScalar(distance) ); //set distance move the camera forward to your needs
  viewer.navigation.setView(camera.position,viewer.navigation.getTarget())
```

Also see [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-debugger.tool/blob/0b754de2f8b3678d90ba35b9d5945816ffee4e6e/partials/setView.html#L33) and [here](https://github.com/search?q=org%3AAutodesk-Forge+navigation.setView&type=Code) for code samples putting the above into practice.

They conceded that this could be a bug but didn't provide more details - will chase them up but guess they got other priorities for the moment like to maintain the newly released Viewer v7.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Please keep us posted if there is any update.